# How to know if a facebook friend has a significant other but does not want to disclose?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to use facebook api to get my friends' relationship status:

```
FB.api("/me/friends", {
        fields: "id, name, relationship_status, significant_other, picture.type(large)"
    }, function (response) {
    if (response.data) {
        ...
        $.each(response.data, function (index, data) {

            if (data.significant_other) {
               // If has a significant other
            } else {
               // If do not have a significant other
            }

        });
    }
});
```

I tried to determine if a friend has a significant other by looking at the significant_other field. But how can I know if my friend has a significant other but doesn't want to disclose?

Comment: `how can I know if my friend has a significant other but doesn't want to disclose?` Ask them directly? If the information isn't available via the API, it's not available.

Comment: Ugh. App devs wanting to do stuff like this is one of the biggest reasons I hate Facebook apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution. If relationship_status equals "In a relationship" but data.significant_other is not in the data. Then that means the friend has a significant_other but does not want to disclose.

Answer (score 0):

If data isn't accessible via the API, there's no way to access that data via the API

This is pretty much a tautology, but if the data were accessible to you, you'd have it via the API call you just included in your question